# What is the best way to load data to the following structure from database?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

The database schema is as follows

**Employee**

- EmployeeID(int, pk)
- FirstName(nvarchar)
- LastName(nvarchar)
- Email(nvarchar)
- EmployeeType(int)
- Salary(decimal)
- HourlyRate(decimal)

**Benefits**

- BenefitID (int, pk)
- Benefit (nvarchar)
- EmployeeID (int, fk)

Employee table holds all the employee data. Salary field applies to fulltime employee and the hourly rate applies to hourly employee. Benefits only apply to Full Time employee.

I have setup a service class that will return all the employees.
I also want to initialize all the benefits to the Salaried Employee object. I have setup a check for employee-type using a switch statement and then create the instance of the object and add it to the collection.

This will work perfectly.

The issue I have is every time I add a new type of employee then I will have to modify the Employee service and add logic to switch statement to handle the new type of employee. This breaks the open close principle.

My question is what is the best way to load data from the database to the objects in this type of scenario?

```
public enum EmployeeType
{
    FullTime =1,
    PartTime =2
}

public class EmployeeBenefit
{
    private string _benefit;
    private Employee _employee;

    public int EmployeeId { get { return Employee.Id; } }
    public Employee Employee { get { return _employee; } }
    public string Benefit { get { return _benefit; } }

    public EmployeeBenefit(Employee emp, string benefit)
    {
        _benefit = benefit;
        _employee = emp;
    }
}

public abstract class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public abstract EmployeeType Type { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class SalariedEmployee: Employee
{
    private ICollection<EmployeeBenefit> _benefits;

    public SalariedEmployee()
    {
        _benefits = new List<EmployeeBenefit>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<EmployeeBenefit> Benefits { get {return _benefits;} }
    public double Salary { get; set; }

    public override EmployeeType Type
    {
        get { return EmployeeType.FullTime; }
    }

    public void AddBenefit(string benefit)
    {
        EmployeeBenefit ebenefit = new EmployeeBenefit(this, benefit);

        if (Benefits.Contains(ebenefit))
            _benefits.Add(ebenefit);
    }

    public void RemoveBenefit(string benefit)
    {
        EmployeeBenefit ebenefit = new EmployeeBenefit(this, benefit);

        if(_benefits.Contains(ebenefit))
            _benefits.Remove(ebenefit);
    }
}

public class PartTimeEmployee : Employee
{
    public override EmployeeType Type
    {
        get { return EmployeeType.PartTime; }
    }

    public double HourlyRate { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeService
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAll() {         
        List<Employee> _lst = new List<Employee>();

        using(var db = new EmployeeContext)
        {

            foreach(Employee e in db.Employees)
            {

                switch(e.Type){
                    case EmployeeType.PartTime:
                        PartTimeEmployee pt = new PartTimeEmployee();
                        //initialize the values of parttime employee like hourly rate

                        _lst.Add(pt);
                        break;
                    case EmployeeType.FullTime:
                        SalariedEmployee se = new SalariedEmployee();
                        //initialize the value of salaried employees like benefits, salary
                        _lst.Add(se);
                        break;
                }

            }


        }

        return _lst;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can move this logic in factory class....class will have job to check type and create instance of appropriate type..Basically you are moving switch statements in that class and have to modify only that class every time

Comment: I thought about using factory method which will return a proper instance of the Employee but how do i set all the relative properties like benefits, hourly rate and salary as they are based on child objects. I am confused here.

Comment: how about adding interface like IPartTimeEmployee, ISalariedEmployee etc

Comment: I can move the Salary and Benefits to ISalariedEmployee and the HourlyRate to IPartTimeEmployee but still the question remains how can do i load the data to respective properites. I can check if the object returned from the factory class is a type of ISalariedEmployee or IPartTimeEmployee and set the values but again i introduce a logic that  checks for the type of object being returned in the service class. Am I thinking the right way?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is simply keep the employee type as String attribute in the Employee class , and add the types dynamically to the Employee class. I don't see the actual need of an Employee Type class here.

If you absolutely need such a class, declare it as a class and not an enum, and have a string attribute which will be the name of the type. After that with every new type you get from the query, initialize an `new EmployeeType()` and add that string with a setter. Then set that EmployeeType to the Employee class.

According to me that is a much better design because you won't need to hard code the string values in the enums.

And for the benefit thing, what you can do is have a benefits attribute to the concrete Employee class(or name it something else as you already have an abstract Employee). And set a value to the benefit only if the type of employee is salaried. That's how I would do it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I have a question. Since Benefits only apply to the salaried employee, I have to query the database to load the benefits of an employee and call the AddBenefit function; where as for hourly employee i do not have to do anything as benefits do not apply.  So if my service class has a function that returns all the employee how do i set all the values from the database. Employee being a abstract class so I need to pass the instance of Salaried or Hourly,

Comment: The code that I have is using a switch statement to check the instance works but I am looking for a better way to load the data as If I have to add more types of employee then I have to come back and modify the switch statement to handle it . Do this make sense?

Comment: What you can do is have a benefits attribute to the concrete Employee class(or name it something else as you already have an abstract Employee). And set a value to the benefit only if the type of employee is salaried. That's how I would do it.

Comment: Thank you Pritam but that is a work around. As for HourlyEmployee there are no benefits so moving benefits to abstract class does not make sense from a OOP stand point. If I move the benefit to abstract class then this property will be accessible to any class that inherits from Employee class. :-(

Comment: I see what you are saying. Then the only way is to create separate concrete classes for each of the types.

Comment: As I mentioned before the code I have works but I feel like some thing is missing here or can be improved. Lets say if I add ContractorEmployee as a type of employee  then I have to edit the service class to handle this type of employee by altering the switch statement. There has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Instead of using switch you can use traditional factory patterns by changing it to if else loop. Otherwise I guess your approach is correct if you don't want to have the benefits attribute in the abstract class.